# could not found Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
 given name 'Theme.AppCompat'.
```

**build.gradle**

[image]

**styles.xml**

[image]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

[image]

**logcat**

[image]

Comment: you should remove support v4 and update your dependencies and add core-utils check my answer

Comment: i do that but nothing changed....

Comment: theme.appcompat should add something after this like my answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove `supportv4` library and add:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1"
```

And (if you dont) include Google's Maven repository in your top-level `build.gradle` file (more info [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup#add-library)).

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must
        // instead use:
        //
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
    }
}
```

Also update compile with implementation and make sure all dependencies are updated to the latest version like:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Last replace in style and try something like:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone using Jetpack Compose, you can follow the approach below:

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.0")
```

and then the style can be set like this. Note the **android** keyword before the Theme.

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
```